# Very old Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, satoshi-nakamoto, android

What I am going to share with you will make you very surprised. I will quickly jump in to the topic as I need some help here.

I have one of the oldest wallet key from 2009 Dec.
I used to play an MMO game on my HTC G1 Android mobile. S.Nakamoto and his developer team mates were also there and we used to play together. I dont remember the name of the game anymore but it was just a shooting game with only 3 or maybe 4 characters and you could have a team of 4 people divided into two teams and play a death match. there was a also small chat window through which i got to know about the BTC as they told me about it. First I read the whitepaper and when I got back on the game the next day I was very excited and I told them this is great i would like to mine. Long story short, they onboarded me and also helped me to setup my wallet. There was also a mobile app by which i could watch in real time the blocks and transactions. I dont remember what that app was maybe it was G-Miner or something like that.

All I have now is some old keys (Private Keys) but when I try to log in to my wallet it shows "0" balance and no transactions at all. I remember that there was a big amount of bitcoins in it so I think there is something wrong, maybe I am not importing the wallet correctly.

By the way the BIP32 and BIP39 was mainstream from 2013 onwards but They taught me how to convert the private key to a 12 word seed phrase back in 2009. But somehow I do not have those seed words, I cant find them. I remember converting the private keys to some SHA256 hash. As even back in 2009 there was some tool that could do that.

please guide me and help me out and whoever successfully helped me I promise to share 2% of my BTCs.

Maybe what i need to know now what was the oldest BIP standard? was it BIP 001? and then if I could convert my "Entropy Hexa Hash" to the correct BIP reference then I could have the correct private key and the seed words to access my wallet. do you get it what I am saying?

Thank you
Oldman

Comment: if you look at the bitcoin development github you will find that the bip001 started from 11 years ago: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0001/process.png

Answer (score 1):

> **There was also a mobile app by which i could watch in real time the blocks and transactions.**

The first Bitcoin app was probably Electrum in 2011

> **I dont remember what that app was maybe it was G-Miner or something like that.**

Unlikely. ["The first version of GMiner was released on September 21, 2018"](https://github.com/dockminer/gminer)

> **if I could convert my "Entropy Hexa Hash" to the correct BIP reference then I could have the correct private key and the seed words to access my wallet.**

The first [Bitcoin *Improvement* Proposal (BIP)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Improvement_Proposals) was created in 2011 - so any feature present in 2009 will not have been first defined by a BIP.

An "Entropy Hexa Hash" could conceivably be used to generate a private key but, so far as I know, no one in 2009 would have written that hash down in preference to writing down the private key or, arguably more usefully, backing up the wallet.dat file. I don't know where in the application Bitcoin core (then "Bitcoin") would have made that entropy information available.

Bitcoin core does not and has never supported the use of seed-phrases (recovery phrases) like those defined in BIP-39.

> **All I have now is some old keys (Private Keys)**

Importing those into a wallet application and getting the wallet to rescan the blockchain should tell you accurately whether those keys ever had control over any money. You would see a list of transactions involving the public key derived from each of the private keys in 2009.

---

> **i converted the orginial keys to something else for keeping them secure ... You could simply take the private key and convert it via a cryptographic tool into SHA256 hash**

The process that produces a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is [not reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function). Therefore you will not be able to recover a private-key from a hash of a private-key.

Comment: whether or not bitcoin supports BIP-30 recovery phrase that is not the question. The idea behind convering private keys to understandbale words was there right from the beginning. And there was also an option to convert the private key to BaseXX or different cryptographic standards. And I did that.Since now there are 12 word and 24 word seed phrases I am wondering if I could convert the key that I have to the seed words and import in Electrum wallet. But when I do that I see 0 balance so that means I am not using the right conversaion method.

Comment: There was an app on Android HTC mobile phone .APK format that could show  how many blocks are mined and how many transactions are being done in real time. Maybe none of you would know this because  you didnt even know in 2009 that bitcoin was existed at that time. only some one who was involveds in bitcoin from 2009 is maybe able to help me.

Comment: that app was not launched on google Market (Play store) it was available on Android (Blackmarket App)

Comment: what I am trying to do now is to generate xpub keys from the entropy hash that I have (because i converted the orginial keys to something else for keeping them secure). And then i use those xpub keys on blockchain.com to check if thats the correct wallet but i see zero balance. please let me know where can i see bitcoin block explorer? is blockchain.com is the right place?

Comment: the entropy information was not available in the bitcoin core. You could simply take the private key and convert it via a cryptographic tool into SHA256 hash or other cyrptographic standards like binary etc.....

Comment: See extended answer